# Clojure Koans: Trouble Understanding the Section on Sequence Comprehensions

Tags: clojure, sequences

I'm new to Clojure, so I've been going through the [Clojure Koans](https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans) the last few days. Things were going fairly well until the [section on sequence comprehensions](https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans/blob/master/src/koans/11_sequence_comprehensions.clj). I'm struggling with this section. The [answers](https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans/blob/master/resources/koans.clj) are available, but I don't understand *how* they arrived at these answers. I've read quite a bit about Clojure the last two days, but it's so much different than Ruby that it's taking me a while to understand it.

There are five "problems" in the section and I can't figure them out. Here are two examples of problems that particularly confused me:

```
"And also filtering"
(= '(1 3 5 7 9)
  (filter odd? (range 10))
  (for [index __ :when (odd? index)]
    index))

"And they trivially allow combinations of the two transformations"
(= '(1 9 25 49 81)
  (map (fn [index] (* index index))
    (filter odd? (range 10)))
  (for [index (range 10) :when __]
    __))
```

For people experienced with Clojure, could you explain how they arrived at the solutions for this section? No matter how much I read about sequences, I just can't wrap my head around this section. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you understand `map` and `filter` functions and I guess they are also present in Ruby. Let me give you an example and probably that can help you understand `for` use in this case.

```
(map <some function to map a value> 
  (filter <some function to return true OR false to filter values>
          <a sequence of values>))
```

The above code does some filtering on a sequence of values using `filter` and then map each value of the filtered sequence to some other value using `map` function.

`for` basically allows you do same thing as shown below

```
(for [index <a sequence of values> 
     :when <some expression to return true OR false by check index value>]
     (<some expression to map a value i.e transform index to something else>))
```

I hope the above example will allow you to be able to map how the `map` and `filter` code can be expressed using `for`

Comment: Thanks, seeing those typed out like that helped a great deal.

Answer (score 1):

That explanation helped and after a few more days of immersing myself in Clojure, I feel much more comfortable with the language.  To make sure I understand, I'll walk through those two tests.

```
"And also filtering"
(= '(1 3 5 7 9)
  (filter odd? (range 10))
  (for [index (range 10) :when (odd? index)]
    index))
```

`'(1 3 5 7 9)` is a list of all the odd numbers between 0 and 9.
`(filter odd? (range 10))` returns a list of all items from the collection `(range 10)` that evaluate to true when checked against `odd?`. The return value is equal to the first list.
`(for)` is basically a for loop. It's iterative. `(for [index (range 10)] index)` would bind all of the numbers between 0 and 9 to the variable `index` and then return `index`, correct?
So `(for [index __ :when (odd? index)] index))` adds the condition that `index` is an odd number. The return value is equal to the first two.

Is that correct?

```
"And they trivially allow combinations of the two transformations"
(= '(1 9 25 49 81)
  (map (fn [index] (* index index))
    (filter odd? (range 10)))
  (for [index (range 10) :when (odd? index)]
    (* index index)))
```

Here the `map` function takes a function. This anonymous function takes an arguments and multiplies that argument by itself. `map` is going to apply this function to each element in the collection it is passed.  That collection is the odd numbers between 0 and 9.

`for` is going to set each number from 0 to 9 to the variable `index` when it is odd and then return a lazy sequence with each of these numbers squared.

Am I correct in that explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand how `for` works? Have you [read about it in the Clojure API docs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/for)? If you know how to use `for`, then you won't have to do anything to "arrive at" the solutions for these 2 problems; they will be self-evident.

The purpose of these problems is for you to infer how `for` works. If they're not helping you to do that, it would be better for you to read up on the subject. If you look up some information on `for`, but find it hard to understand, please edit this question to specify exactly what is confusing you, and I (or others) can try to explain.